# Scale IdentityServer4 across regions

Tags: azure-sql-database, identityserver4, distributed-computing, azure-data-sync

I am currently running IDS4 as a single instance in one region (single database for configuration and operational store). I now have to distribute the installation across two regions so that services/users in region A access IDS in region A and services/users in region B access IDS in region B.

Both instances should access the same datastore, but IDS in region B should not have to make cross-region read queries to the database in region A.

We use Azure SQL Server and the geo-replication feature which offers a single writable instance (either in region A or B) and multiple readable instances. We pointed IDS in region B to a read-only instance in the same region, but this does not work because IDS has to write operational data like persistent grants.

Is there a recommended architecture to achieve this or do you have any experience implementing a multi-region and load-balanced IDS deployment? Is it possible to configure IDS to use a different database for write operations and the database in the same region for read operations?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please spend a minute to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that you will find a recommended architecture for a scenario like this due to how much of this problem is in your business domain. Also, there is nothing out of the box in Identity Server 4 library or its supporting libraries that would satisfy your criteria.

Having said that, I've had a similar requirement (unrelated to Identity Server 4 but identical functional requirements in a nutshell) and it should be possible to adapt the same idea in your case.

Firstly, your only problem like you've said is the fact that out of the box, using the Identity Server 4 EF package, the `PersistedGrantStore` uses one `IPersistedGrantDbContext` which does both writes and reads from the database. So in order to solve this, you basically need to create your own implementation of `IPersistedGrantStore` and in that custom implementation you could technically use two different `DbContext` types, one of which would be created using a connection string to single writeable instance of database and would only be used for implementing interface methods that do writes and another one would be used for read methods only and would use connection string for read only instance of the database.

Basic idea of the above summary is below:

```
public class MyCustomPersistedGrantStore : IPersistedGrantStore
{
    private readonly WriteOnlyPersistedGrantDbContext _writeContext;
    private readonly ReadOnlyPersistedGrantDbContext _readContext;  

    public PersistedGrantStore(WriteOnlyPersistedGrantDbContext writeContext, ReadOnlyPersistedGrantDbContext readContext)
    {
        _writeContext = writeContext;
        _readContext = readContext;
    }

    public Task StoreAsync(PersistedGrant token)
    {
        //Use _writeContext to implement storage logic
    }

    public Task<PersistedGrant> GetAsync(string key)
    {
        //Use _readContext to implement read logic
    }

    ...other interface methods
}
```

All you need after implementing your custom version is to add your implementation of `IPersistedGrantStore` as well as the `DbContext`'s into DI system .

Lastly, it is worthwhile to note that if you stop using `.AddOperationalStore(...config)` then you also forfeit usage of `TokenCleanupHostService` so you would need to implement that as well.

Comment: @lunzi You marked this as the accepted answer but commented on the answer by Alberto Morillo that you had it working using his suggestion. As we have the same problem I was wondering what you ended up doing.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Geo-replication you can use Azure SQL Data Sync to have writable replicas of Azure SQL Database, defining one of them as the hub database and the others as the member database. Synchronization between all databases can be configured bidirectional thus all databases are updateable. You can start configuring Azure SQL Data Sync on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync) documentation.

Comment: We successfully set up data sync between the two databases and it is working fine. In contrast to near real-time data replication of Azure SQL geo-replication, data sync only replicates every 5 minutes. I am wondering if this could lead to problematic situations. In normal operation a user always hits the same region and thus the same database. In case of a failover, the worst case would be that the user has to re-authenticate because the persisted grant was not synced. Any other data (e.g. configuration data) would be synced after the region becomes available again.

Comment: On the sync frequency you can choose seconds. "If you choose On, enter a number and select Seconds, Minutes, Hours, or Days in the Sync Frequency section." Read more here on "Automatic Sync" setting. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync?wt.mc_id=MVP#create-sync-group

Comment: I checked out the docs already and it says: The minimal duration between synchronizations is five minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the process of hammering out the kinks in my own private fork of [IdentityServer4.Contrib.CosmosDB](https://github.com/jnhaffey/IdentityServer4.Contrib.CosmosDB). If you take a look at the (very unfinished atm) source code, you'll get a rough understanding of how to implement your own DB provider that gracefully handles such a requirement. Actually, you may want to hypothetically think about using a NoSQL datastore for IDServer, as I believe it's 'optimized' for multi-region reads/writes compared to SQL Server.